# How do i solve this KNIME error: Java exit code 2

Tags: java, windows, knime

I have downloaded the [zip file](https://github.com/kmansouri/QSAR-ready/releases/download/2.5.8/knime_4.5.1_QSAR-ready_2.5.8.zip) from [this page](https://github.com/kmansouri/QSAR-ready/releases).
It contains a KNIME workflow and the KNIME GUI version 4.5.

I installed KNIME and set the workspace to `.\knime_4.5.1\knime-workspace` so that I can see that the workflow has been properly loaded.

In the page the author said
"The workflow can also be executed in batch mode using the command line:
`[knime path]\knime -reset -nosplash -nosave -application org.knime.product.KNIME_BATCH_APPLICATION -workflowDir="[knime path]\knime-workspace\QSAR-ready_2.5.8" -workflow.varaiable=cmd_input,"[input path]\inputfile",String"`

First I noticed that there is a typo in  `-workflow.varaiable` and I changed it to `-workflow.variable`.

I used absolute path that start with `C:\...`

when I run the command I get this error message
[image: KNIME error]

#### Things that I tried

- To better understand where is the error I tried executing the command starting from the simplest form and adding step by step more info. I can run `C:\...\knime_4.5.1\knime -reset -nosplash -nosave -application` just fine,  but if I add  `org.knime.product.KNIME_BATCH_APPLICATION` I get the same error